# How can I turn **kwargs into named variables with values? python

Tags: python, variables, exec, keyword-argument

The following code did not work, any help would be appreciated.

```
def testfunc(**kwargs):
    for i in kwargs:
        exec(f"global {i}, {i} = kwargs['{i}']")
    print(a,b,c)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testfunc(a=1,b=2,c=3)
```

Comment: Don’t. There are all sorts of nastiness that could be done with such a thing, but no useful purpose it could possibly serve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `globals()` to get the global variable dictionary. Then you can update it directly instead of using `exec()`.

```
def testfunc(**kwargs):
    globals().update(kwargs)
    print(a,b,c)
```

Comment: `testfunc(a=0, b=0, c=0, len=lambda *_: "where is your god now?")`

Comment: @user3840170 I never said that this was a good idea.

Comment: I just had to try that... Thanks for the laugh :)

Comment: @user3840170 Similar problems happen to people who use `list`, `dict`, and `input` as variables.

Comment: I tried this works. many thanks. but can anyone please tell me what the problem is? Do you mean this may pass illegal variables into the functions?

Comment: it will turn all the keyword arguments into global variables. Which means it can overwrite built-in names like `len` if you're not careful how you call it.

Comment: It's rarely necessary to create global variables dynamically like this. You should be using dictionaries.

Comment: At least when people use such names for *local* variables, the problem is contained to just one function. This, however, is a time bomb waiting to explode.